# How to set Time Based condition in a macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Greeting to ALL,

Seeking Attention of experts in Google Apps Script.
Objective is to fine tune a existing macro and make it run time based condition, to import a csv data file import.
Google Sheet link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aK-Ykt6q2Iui7OYHEKM1zkdiabzq9NaUV9dv1vBQrXs/edit?usp=sharing
Script for macro used 'Loaddata'-
''''

```
function Loaddata() {
  
const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var    s1 = ss.getSheetByName('import');
var range_1 = s1.getRange('B6');

// Date Variables 
var date01 = range_1.getValue();
    date01 = Utilities.formatDate(date01, "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var cell_1 = s1.getRange('E2')
var rownum = range_1.getRowIndex();
var date02 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd");

// Time Conditions refference
var time01 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"IST","HH:mm:ss").valueOf()     // current Time - for trigger, to activiate downloading http link
var cell_2 = s1.getRange('I2') 
const timeT = Utilities.formatDate(cell_2,"IST","HH:mm:ss").valueOf()

// Ranges for data import & copying 
var range_2 = s1.getRange('A5:B5');
var range_3 = s1.getRange('C5') 
var range_4 = s1.getRange('K5');
var range_5 = s1.getRange('D7:D20');
var range_6 = s1.getRange('D7:I20');
var range_7 = s1.getRange('B6:I21');

//var rangeTarget_1 for Paste & set values
var rangeTarget_2 = s1.getRange('A6:B21');
var rangeTarget_3 = s1.getRange('C6');
var rangeTarget_4 = s1.getRange('K6');
var rangeTarget_7 = s1.getRange('B6:I21');

// Trigger for downloading at 6:00 pm Mon to Fri 

  if (time01()<timeT(),
    cell_1.setValue('Previous'),
    cell_1.setValue('Latest'))
    
      if (date01.valueOf() < date02.valueOf()) {

      s1.insertRowsBefore(rownum,15);
      
      range_2.copyTo(rangeTarget_2);
      range_3.copyTo(rangeTarget_3);
      range_4.copyTo(rangeTarget_4);
      range_5.setHorizontalAlignment('left');
      range_6.setFontWeight(null).setBackground('BACKGROUND');
      range_7.copyTo(rangeTarget_7,CopyPastType.PASTE_VALUES);

      Logger.log(rownum,date01);

       
  };
}
```

''''
Objective is to activate importdata function to get csv data at a particular time (let say 18:00:00, IST). If condition is true & importdata checks current date (in cell B6 in 'import' Tab) and download csv data.

The Macro scripted checks date (in table), if it is not today, then macro inserts 15 rows and update date (to today) and use Imortdata function for downloading csv file. And store data (paste values only) in these new inserted rows. Any suggestion to improve/optimize this part is welcomed.
Now want add Trigger point in cell I2. It is to be matched and then value in E2 is updated ('Previous' / 'Latest'). This (E2) controls date formula in Col B6:B. It is reqd. to check correct date in formulating html reference (used for 'Importdata' function).
Script runs for desired output if Time trigger steps are excluded.
Why time and date triggers reqd - because reqd Trade Report are generated from Mon to Friday @ 6:00 pm.
Tried to clarify mostly everything, pl. feel free if required more info.

Pl. do help this novice app script learner.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: The function is most likely throwing errors. Check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for failed executions, and view those logs to learn more about why the function fails. You can run your function in the script editor when testing. See [Range.setBackgroundObject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundobjectcolor) to learn how to use theme colors.

Comment: @doubleunary Script is for ' Loaddata' only. Time trigger if excluded is giving results..

Comment: Questions on this site should be specific, Please clarify what is this question about. I.E. if you are looking for help on creating a trigger, show what you have tried to create the trigger and add a brief description of your search efforts about creating that trigger.

P.S. Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior please don't include greetings, thanks, signature and other chit-chat.

Comment: This is the valueOf() a String `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "HH:mm:ss").valueOf()` not the valueOf() a Date()

Comment: @ Cooper Suggest correct syntax/line, if you may pl.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make it a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks Cooper for the valuable inputs. Created a Const. of time difference value equivalent to 6:00 pm (i.e. right side of decimal of numeric date value) to create a reference value to match now() condition. This is giving desired output. Any other inputs / suggestions for cleanup and improvement will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there @RobinU! I am glad that your question got answered. Could you please document your end product on an answer in order to have better documentation about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround the based on inputs from Cooper. Created a new var for Time baseline for comparison and used that value to get results.

''''

```
function Loaddata() {
  
const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var    s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Import');
var range_1 = s1.getRange('B6');

// Date Variables 
var date01 = range_1.getValue();
    date01 = Utilities.formatDate(date01, "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var cell_1 = s1.getRange('E2') ;
var cell_2 = s1.getRange('F2') ;

var rownum = range_1.getRowIndex();
var date02 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "yyyy-MM-dd");

// Time Condition refference
var time01 = s1.getRange('H2') ; // Time for Trigger   
var timeT = s1.getRange('G2')  ; // current Time - for trigger, to start downloading file

// Ranges for data import & copying 
var range_2 = s1.getRange('A5:B5') ;
var range_3 = s1.getRange('C5') ; 
var range_4 = s1.getRange('K5') ;
var range_5 = s1.getRange('D7:D20') ;
var range_6 = s1.getRange('D7:I20') ;

//var rangeTarget_1 for Paste & set values
var rangeTarget_2 = s1.getRange('A6:B21') ;
var rangeTarget_3 = s1.getRange('C6') ;
var rangeTarget_4 = s1.getRange('K6') ;
var rangeTarget_7 = s1.getRange('B6:I21') ;
var newData = s1.getRange('B6:I21') ;

// Trigger for downloading at 6:00 pm Mon to Fri 

  if ( cell_2 < 5 & date01.valueOf() > date02.valueOf(),
  
      cell_1.setValue('Latest'));
    else
      cell_1.setValue('Previous') ;

    s1.insertRowsBefore(rownum,15);
    range_2.copyTo(rangeTarget_2);
    range_3.copyTo(rangeTarget_3);

    range_4.copyTo(rangeTarget_4);
        
    // wait to complete all the changes on the spreadsheet
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

    var cell_3 = rangeTarget_4.getValue();

    if (cell_3 !== "TRUE",
      range_5.setHorizontalAlignment('left') & 
      range_6.setFontWeight(null).setBackground('BACKGROUND') &
      rangeTarget_7.setValues(newData.getValues()));

      Logger.log(time01,timeT);
};
```

''''